# Как подсунуть значение энама (число) в виде строки в другую строку в compile time

Tags: c++, c

так работает:

```
#define SMTH "smth"
const char* const str = "\"" SMTH  "\""; // будет "smth"
```

как сделать так:

```
enum {number = 1};
const char* const str = "\"" number "\""; // нужно "1", но такой синтаксис не поддерживается
```

Comment: https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum

Comment: @tocic прочие зависимости не нужны, желательно средствами языка

Comment: Там MIT лицензия, можете посмотреть реализацию и сделать так же.

Answer (score 2):

С enum-ом (а также с любой инициализируемой переменной) не получится, поскольку  текстовые подстановки проводятся *[препроцессором](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%A1%D0%B8)*, т.е. на шаге *предшествующем* собственно компиляции.

С помощью директив препроцессора `#define` можно заключить в кавычки *значение* другого макроса (т.е. имени, определенного в `#define`) следующим образом:

```
#define STR(x) #x
#define XSTR(x) STR(x)
```

Здесь `STR(x)` заключает в кавычки свой аргумент (т.е. тот текст, который мы размещаем в скобках),
а `XSTR(x)` передает в качестве аргумента в STR `x` с уже сделанными подстановками (раскрытием макросов).

Тогда, если мы определим макрос

```
#define N   222
```

то можем подставить в текст программы значение `N` в кавычках:

```
const char *t = XSTR(N);
```

получая после препроцессора:

```
const char *t = "222";
```

(это можно увидеть, запустив компилятор с ключем `-E` (например *g++ -E t.cpp*))

Стоит заметить, что макрос `XSTR()` создает строки в том числе и из содержимого других макросов с аргументами. Например, код:

```
#define YNX(x) ({if ((x) > 0) cout << "Yes"; else cout << "No";})
....
cout << "XSTR(YNX(N)) = `"<< XSTR(YNX(N)) << "`\n";
cout << "STR(XSTR(YNX(N))) = `" << STR(XSTR(YNX(N))) << "`\n";
```

напечатает при выполнении программы

```
XSTR(YNX(N)) = `({if ((222) > 0) cout << "Yes"; else cout << "No";})`
STR(XSTR(YNX(N))) = `XSTR(YNX(N))`
```

Comment: да про макрос знаю, но у меня значение именно в енаме хранится из хедера предоставляемой другой системой, видимо sprintf придется делать

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, что-то наподобие такого?

```
enum {number = 1};
const std::string value = std::to_string(number);
const char* str = value.c_str() ;
```

Comment: это runtime, мне надо compile time